# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails"

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, openid

I'm trying to work through the Masq OpenId Server installation instructions found [here](https://github.com/dennisreimann/masq).

However, when I get to Step 2 of the installation steps, I get the following error when running **bundle install**

```
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    masq (>=0) ruby depends on
      rails (~> 3.2.2) ruby
    rails (4.2.1)
```

Now, I "think" this is happening because some dependency is explicitly expecting Rails 3.2.2. (Please correct me if I'm wrong)

My question is, is there something I can do to try and make the dependency stop looking for an older version of Rails?

Thanks for your time!  :)

Answer (score 0):

it's masq that's depending on rails. check out the gemspec:
https://github.com/dennisreimann/masq/blob/master/masq.gemspec

the problem is that the generated rails app is probably using rails4 and masq is using rails3.

2 options:
- use rails3 for the app
- update masq for rails4

I would personally go with the first option.
For the 2nd route, take a look at https://github.com/dennisreimann/masq/pulls and the forks from the project, some of which seem to have been updated for rails4.

Comment: Thank you for the response!  Unfortunately, using Rails 3 is not at an option for us at this time.  We also don't really have the time to fork and update the project.  So we'll probably just move onto using a PHP implementation for now.  Thanks again!